# Android: ProgressDialog not showing in AsyncTask called in onCreate()

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I have a AsyncTask which will be executed in the `onCreate` method. However, my ProgressDialog isn't showing up. And from debugging, it is confirmed that the AsyncTask is being executed.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lifestyle);
        context = getApplicationContext();

        new testAsync().execute();
}

private class testAsync extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected  void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this); // tried with context, no difference
            pDialog.setTitle("Inserting sample data");
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait. This dialog will be dismissed upon completion.");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
          //  TableControllerReadings TCR = new TableControllerReadings(context);
          //  TCR.insertSampleData(getApplicationContext());

            new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                 //delay for 5 seconds
                }
            }, 5000);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take your `pDialog.dismiss();` into the your timer thread.

**Reason:** `onPostExecute()` immediately call because on background task is finished.

Its seprate thread which is on delay so cursor move to the `onPostExecute()`

```
 private class testAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this); // tried with context, no difference
            pDialog.setTitle("Inserting sample data");
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait. This dialog will be dismissed upon completion.");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //  TableControllerReadings TCR = new TableControllerReadings(context);
            //  TCR.insertSampleData(getApplicationContext());

            new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //delay for 5 seconds
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }, 5000);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
         // pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Okay this works well. Not sure where went wrong but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Activity will not show any view until `onResume` method is called. If your `AsyncTask` execution completes before `onResume` call then you will never see the `ProgressDialog`.

So better call `new testAsync().execute();` in `onResume`

Comment: its not mandatory to call in onresume or oncreate it the logic or design which decide when to show.

Comment: I will modify the logic on my end on when the asynctask will execute in `onResume`. I take back my previous comment, apparently it works now.

Answer (score 0):

add `pDialog.show();` in doInBackground and add `new testAsync().execute();` in onResume

Comment: The `.show()` method must be called in the UI thread. Caling it in `doInBackground` gives me "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()".

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine with Thread.sleep(5000); if you want to add delay then use Thread.Sleep(/*time in milisec*/) instead of Timer.Schedule. Because of Timer.Schedule async task is executing so quickly before showing any dialog.